# Convert txt to Stack in Java

Tags: java

I am reading a txt file to convert each word to a token, to then be inserted into a stack. The problem is that when the process ends, the stack always returns a null value.

The content in txt is:

```
one;
two;
tree;
four; home;
six; seven; house;
```

And I do a split for each line to create an array and then loop through an array to fill a stack.After finishing the while I want to see the stack with its values ​​but that's where the stack displays null.

Here if it shows the value:

```
          do{
            temp = buffer.readLine();
            String x;
            x = temp;               
            String []tokens = x.split(" ");          
            for(int i=0; i<tokens.length; i++){
                String xx = tokens[i];
                if(xx != null){
                    stacks.push(xx);
                    System.out.println("Stack xx: " + stacks);
                }
            }
        }while(temp != null);
```

When exiting the while the stack appears as null:

```
System.out.println("Stack show null value: " + stacks);
```

The code is:

```
    package proyectofinal;

     public class proyectofinal{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO code application logic here
            ManageDocument read = new ManageDocument();
            read.ReadTxt("test.txt");
        }

     }



    package proyectofinal;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.util.Stack;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Stack;
    public class ManageDocument {
        public void ReadTxt(String name){
        try{     
            Stack<String> stacks = new Stack<String>();
            FileReader read = new FileReader(name);
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(read);            
            String temp="";         
            do{
                temp = buffer.readLine();
                String x;
                x = temp;               
                String []tokens = x.split(" ");          
                for(int i=0; i<tokens.length; i++){
                    String xx = tokens[i];
                    if(xx != null){
                        stacks.push(xx);
                        System.out.println("Stack xx: " + stacks);
                    }
                }
            }while(temp != null);             
            System.out.println("Stack show null value: " + stacks);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What’s your program output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a null pointer exception which you are printing in your catch block, that's why you are always getting null as output.

This is because of your do while loop which checks the condition after execution of logic. You have to check null value before executing your logic.

Your code breaks here

```
String []tokens = x.split(" ");
```

if value of x is null.